# Google Speech To Text returns only 1 speaker although the conversation has 2 humans speaking to each other

Tags: google-speech-to-text-api

One of the features in my app is to record a conversation between two individuals (this could be at most 3) and then use the Google Speech To Text version `v1p1beta1` to obtain a diarized version of the speech contained in that recording.

The specifics: The audio recording is done on the client side using this code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false})
    .then(function(stream) {
        userMediaStreamAOnly    =   stream;
    })
```

...and...

```
vcAudioOnlyRecorder =   new MediaRecorder(userMediaStreamAOnly, { mimeType: 'audio/webm' });
```

The above code produces a Base64 encoded string whose media type is "audio/webm". So far so good.
Following are the values assigned to `RecognitionConfig` and `RecognitionAudio`:

```
joConfig    =   new JSONObject();
joConfig.put("encoding", AudioEncoding.ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED_VALUE);
joConfig.put("sampleRateHertz", 48000);
joConfig.put("languageCode", languageCode);
joConfig.put("enableWordTimeOffsets", true);
joConfig.put("enableAutomaticPunctuation", true);
                    
jsonObjectDiarizationConfig     =   new JSONObject();
jsonObjectDiarizationConfig.put("enableSpeakerDiarization", Boolean.TRUE);
jsonObjectDiarizationConfig.put("minSpeakerCount", 2);
jsonObjectDiarizationConfig.put("maxSpeakerCount", 3);
joConfig.put("diarizationConfig", jsonObjectDiarizationConfig);
                    
jsonObjectRecognitionMetadata   =   new JSONObject();
jsonObjectRecognitionMetadata.put("interactionType", InteractionType.DISCUSSION);
jsonObjectRecognitionMetadata.put("industryNaicsCodeOfAudio", 512290);
jsonObjectRecognitionMetadata.put("microphoneDistance", MicrophoneDistance.NEARFIELD_VALUE);
jsonObjectRecognitionMetadata.put("originalMediaType", OriginalMediaType.AUDIO);
jsonObjectRecognitionMetadata.put("recordingDeviceType", RecordingDeviceType.PC);
jsonObjectRecognitionMetadata.put("audioTopic", "Test");
joConfig.put("metadata", jsonObjectRecognitionMetadata);
                        
joConfig.put("model", "default");
joConfig.put("useEnhanced", Boolean.TRUE);
                    
joAudio     =   new JSONObject();
joAudio.put("content", Base64AudioContents);
                        
joPayLoad   =   new JSONObject();
joPayLoad.put("config", joConfig);
joPayLoad.put("audio", joAudio);
```

I then invoke this URL:

```
https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize?key=
```

to trigger the speech-to-text process.

**I have the Base64 string. Just not sure how to share it here on stackoverflow.**

In return, I get an instance of operation that (somewhere deep down inside the data structure) contains instances of words.

Now here is the problem: Sometimes, the instances of `words` contains two `speaker` tags, namely, 1 and 2, and accurately contain the words spoken by the respective users.
And sometimes, the text (corresponding to the words spoken by the two speakers) is attributed just to one speaker, i.e., the instances of `words` contain only one `speaker` tag, namely, 1.

Question 1: Is this an issue with the quality of my microphone? Note that I am using the microphone that came built in with my lap-top.

Question 2: Should I pass lossless audio to the URL? In which case, I am not sure if MediaDevices supports a lossless format, yet.

Question 3: Is this a technology whose current level of maturity is such that these anomalies are only to be expected?

Comment: I am perturbed by the consistently inconsistent speaker tags in the output. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if there are challenges because you don't specify an audio encoding.  Also, is your audio sampled at 48khz? The most common is 16khz. A mismatch between the sample rate config and the actual sample rate could throw off speaker recognition!

Answer (score 1):

> 1: Is this an issue with the quality of my microphone? Note that I am using the microphone that came built in with my lap-top.

Record the audio from that micrphone, play it back through decent headphones (nothing below $20 would qualify, unless it was a good secondhand deal), and hear for yourself :) It may well be a problem not with the microphone but with the room reflections, background noise, etc.

> 2: Should I pass lossless audio to the URL? In which case, I am not sure if MediaDevices supports a lossless format, yet.

You must have some control over the compression/bitrate of audio from the microphone. Last time I played with video in Chrome, the defaults were terrible, so I'm not sure what they are for audio. YMMV. You must know exactly what the parameters are, though.

> 3: Is this a technology whose current level of maturity is such that these anomalies are only to be expected?

You get what you pay for, too. If you want something with technical support and someone you can call who stands behind the product, you will do well to talk to a company whose sole focus is this technology, and not, for example, turning you into a product :)

The maturity level of the technology is IMHO adequate for most tasks, but who you get the technology from matters a whole lot.

Comment: "Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica".....thanks a lot for the comprehensive response.  Answer to question 1: I have heard the recording back using a pair of headphones costing upwards of USD70. I have to admit that there is some background noise. So lesson learnt: Ensure that the recording happens in a noiseless, quieter place.  Answer to question 2: There is audioBitsPerSecond which is part of options that is used when constructing a MediaRecorder object. I will play around with that. Answer to question 3: I do not know of any other, more reliable source. Please name a few.